# How to move multiple file names?

Tags: rename, filenames, batch-rename

At work I had to rename 650 files. Turns out I skipped one file in the middle. So I added it, but now I have to take the names from subsequent files to the one I added and move them all up 1 "slot".

Here's a screencap:

[image]

All the FILE NAMES after "01_21reaaaallll" must move up one slot, so the "01_21" would replace the "01_21reaaallll", and so on.

Is there a way to do this? Just move the file names, so i dont have to rename every single one again?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want every file in the list to take the name of the preceding file in the list, e.g. `File2` to take name of `File1`, `File3` to take name of `File2`, and so on?

Comment: Exactly @dezlov! Is there a way to do this? I'm trying to use Advanced Renamer, but still couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer).

A so called "shift" of new names is achieved by adding a renaming rule with a script (below). Files have to be sorted by the Name column for this to work, because files are processed sequentially (from top to bottom). The first file is prefixed with a random character so it does not interfere with the next file.

This is how it will look like:

[image: Shifting down new names of files]

**Note:** You can ignore the validation warning. It just tells you that the destination file already exists, but the sequential renaming will still work as expected.

Here is the script used in the PascalScript rule in ReNamer:

```pascal
var
  Temp, Previous: WideString;
begin
  if Previous = '' then
  begin
    Previous := FileName;
    FileName := '@' + FileName;
  end
  else
  begin
    Temp := FileName;
    FileName := Previous;
    Previous := Temp;
  end;
end.
```